# How to reach PostgresCluster in Azure Cloud with a client from local?

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm

I want to access my postgres cluster within my kubernetes within azure cloud with a client (e.g. pgadmin) to search manuelly through data.

At the moment my complete cluster only has 1 ingress that is pointing to a self written api gateway.

I found a few ideas online and tried to add a load balancer in kubernetesd without success.

My postgress cluster in terraform:

```
resource "helm_release" "postgres-cluster" {
  name       = "postgres-cluster"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "postgresql-ha"
  namespace  = var.kube_namespace

  set {
    name  = "global.postgresql.username"
    value = var.postgresql_username
  }

  set {
    name  = "global.postgresql.password"
    value = var.postgresql_password
  }
}
```

Results in a running cluster:

[image]

Now my try to add a load balancer:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "postgresql-loadbalancer" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "v1"
    "kind"       = "Service"
    "metadata"   = {
      "name"      = "postgres-db-lb"
      "namespace" = "${var.kube_namespace}"
    }
    "spec" = {
      "selector" = {
        "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "postgresql-ha"
      }
      "type" = "LoadBalancer"
      "ports" = [{
        "port"       = "5432"
        "targetPort" = "5432"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Will result in:
[image]

But still no success if I try to connect to the external IP and Port:

[image]

Comment: Please confirm whether 5432 port opened in NSG with Public IP range or not? if not if should not allow to access outside and also SSL connection should be require. Try to access the instance inside the cluster once refer this https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-SQL-with-Postgres-for-Kubernetes/1.1/tanzu-postgres-k8s/GUID-accessing.html

Comment: If you have kubectl access to the cluster it might be easier and safer to use port-forward. `kubectl port-forward svc/your-service-name -n your-namespace 5432:5432`, and then you point pgadmin to localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - it was an internal Firewall I was never thinking of. The code is absolutly correct, a loadbalancer do work here.